# how to show post in wp from archive in monthly basis

Tags: wordpress

I want to show wordpress post in monthly basis,means the post which is showing from archive will only be filtered by respected month,Can you help me?
here is the website http://www.paces.solutions/blog/. When you click on january it is showing all blogs and in same for other months also.I want to show the posts monthwise.Is it possible?

Comment: For more chance of getting help, you need to provide some more information about what you are trying to acheive. Some code showing what you have tried, or some examples of what you want to do.

Comment: This is already done by default. If this is not the case, you have most probably changed the main loop for a custom one on your archive.php, which is wrong